# Finding a numerical stable way to evaluate different functions

Tags: numerical-methods

For each of the following functions, suggest a numerical stable way to evaluate $y$ for small $x$ in order to avoid loss of precision:

$y=x^2-\sin(x)^2$ - ignore terms of order $o(x^7$)

$y=\frac{x^2-\sin(x)^2}{2-\sqrt{x+4}}$ - ignore terms of order $o(x^6$)

$y=2x+e^x-e^{3x}$ - ignore terms of order $o(x^3$)

$y=\log(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ - ignore terms of order $o(x^3)=O(x^4$)

$y=\sqrt{e^{-\frac{2}{3}x}-e^{-x}}$ - ignore terms of order $o(x)$

I have never seen something like this before even though I have been taking a course in numerical analysis. I have only been learning how to implement numerical methods. I was never taught why it was necessary, but I am familiar with the floating point architecture, rounding error, loss of precision by subtraction, etc. because I looked it up myself in order to make sense of why I had to learn all that stuff. Therefore I am not sure how to solve this problem properly. However, because of the specifications about ignoring some terms, I think the questioner wants me to do Taylor expansions of one or more terms for each function. But what does little and big o mean in this context? For instance what does $o(x^3)=O(x^4$) mean? Does it mean that I have to Taylor expand to degree 2 and that the error term is of order 3? If this is true, what is then the meaning of $o(x)$? Does it mean that I just have to replace some term with a constant? How do I generally identify what the problem is for each function? I mean what is the problem with evaluating $y=x^2-\sin(x)^2$ for small $x$? Is it that $\sin(x)$ will take on small values that may not be represented perfectly by the floating point architecture so we will get a rounding error? I hope my questions make sense and I will be very grateful for a clarifying answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Indeed, the first step would be to identify the problem, i.e., for which values of $x$ is the formula numerically unstable.
- Typically, the issue in these kinds of formulas is [cancellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_cancellation), i.e., subtracting two nearly-identical numbers.
- Here is a potential solution for the first question: For $x$ close to zero, $x^2$ and $\sin(x)^2$ are nearly the same, so subtracting one from the other will result in a huge loss of precision. We can rewrite the equation as
  \begin{align}
  x^2 - \sin(x)^2 &= (x+\sin(x))(x-\sin(x))\,.
  \end{align}
  Now the first factor is not a problem (because for $x\approx 0$, both $x$ and $\sin(x)$ have the same sign, thus no cancellation). But the second term is still problematic. This can indeed be solved with a Taylor expansion.
  \begin{align}
  \sin(x) &= x - x^3/3! + x^5/5! + O(x^7)... \\
  x^2 - \sin(x)^2 &= (x + \sin(x))(x^3/3! - x^5/5!) + O(x^8)
  \end{align}
  This is already pretty good, but can be improved slightly more (because there might still be some cancellation in the minus sign). Simply factoring out common factors (special case of [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method)) gives us
  \begin{align}
  x^2 - \sin(x)^2 &= x^3(x + \sin(x))(1/3! - x^2/5!) + O(x^8)
  \end{align}
  which is now totally fine for $x\approx 0$.

Comment: What a nice and clear way to step through the process +1.

Comment: That is a very clear answer. Thank you. However, I am still not sure what little and big o means in this context, and why are you writing O(x^7) and then O(x^8)?

Comment: @Jens : $o(x^7)$ is a remainder that is strictly better than $O(x^7)$. In the context of power series, this means the remainder has to be $O(x^8)$, as terms in-between do not occur. /// One could also use $\sin^2x=(1-\cos(2x))/2=x^2-x^4/3+2x^6/45+O(x^8)$ in the first example.

Comment: I found out that if f(x) is in o(x^n) it means that the limit of f(x)/x^n is approaching zero for x->0. Is this correct? If so, why is the 7th order term omitted? The limit of this must be -1/5040. Hence it is not o(x^7).

Comment: So would adding a 7th order term also be acceptable, but adding a 9th order term would not? If yes, why did you omit the 7th order term? Was it just because it was not necessary?